# How to use calcite sql parser to parse sql express with double quotes as literal quote string?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-calcite, sql-parser

I tried calcite SQL parser on version 1.32.0 and 1.36.0.
I used double quote(") as literal quote string in spark sql expression, and set the parameter on my parser config, but it threw a sql parse exception:
*org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.ParseException: Encountered """ at line 1, column 26.
Was expecting one of:
"ABS" ...
"ARRAY" ...
"AVG" ...*
I am not sure if this is bug, because double quote for literal string is not a rare case.

Here is my test case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String sqlQuery = "case  when `Area` in (   \"Region1\", \"Region2\", \"Region3\"  ) then `Sales`  else null end";
    //create spark dialect
    SqlDialect.Context context = SqlDialect.EMPTY_CONTEXT
            .withDatabaseProduct(SqlDialect.DatabaseProduct.SPARK)
            .withUnquotedCasing(Casing.UNCHANGED)
            .withNullCollation(NullCollation.LOW)
            .withIdentifierQuoteString("`")
            .withLiteralQuoteString("\"");
    SqlDialect sparkDialect = new SparkSqlDialect(context);
    SqlParser.Config config = sparkDialect.configureParser(SqlParser.config());
    // Create an SQL parser
    SqlParser parser = SqlParser.create(sqlQuery, config);
    // Parse the query into an AST. Here the exception occurred
    SqlNode sqlNode = parser.parseExpression();
  }
```

If it is not an issue of calcite sql parser, please propose a proper way of parsing the sql expression